# Django AppConfig::ready cannot use module which imports models

Tags: python, django

I wish to run an initialisation function when my django app is loaded, using the AppConfig::ready method.

However, the functionality I wish to run needs to use django models, and you can't import this module at the point that apps.py is imported, because the models aren't fully loaded at this time.

How can I get around this limitation?

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from . import populate_db
from . import server_settings


class ServerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'server'

    def ready(self):
        populate_db.populate_db(server_settings.opt.data_root)
```

Produces there errors:

```
File "/home/ian/dev/obd/django_site/server/apps.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import populate_db
  File "/home/ian/dev/obd/django_site/server/populate_db.py", line 16, in <module>
    import server.models as models
  File "/home/ian/dev/obd/django_site/server/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Scan(models.Model):
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppfunctionRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to automatically run a `populate_db` method in `ready()`. I think you might find it runs sometimes when you don't want it to (e.g. when you run `makemigrations` or `migrate` before the tables have been created in the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the imports inside the ready method, something like:

```
class ServerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'server'
    def ready(self):
        from . import populate_db
        from . import server_settings
        populate_db.populate_db(server_settings.opt.data_root)
```